# CommonJS: How to make http.createServer like method for own module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, commonjs

I think it is cool that I can use following to create instance of httpServer:

```
var express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
```

However if I make my own server class which should return instance of itself how I can do it?

Currently I have for example following:

**server.js:**

```
var Server = function() {
  this.someVar = 1;
};

Server.prototype.someMethod1 = function() {
  console.log("1");
};

Server.prototype.someMethod2 = function() {
  console.log("2");
};

module.exports = Server;
```

And I use it like this:

```
var Server = require("./app/server"),
    server = new Server();
```

Clumsy? I want it like this:

```
var server = require("./app/server").createServer();

// then, do what ever I want with server instance
server.someMethod1();
```

Thnx for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

**server.js**

```
var Server = function() {
  this.someVar = 1;
};

Server.prototype.someMethod1 = function() {
  console.log("1");
};

Server.prototype.someMethod2 = function() {
  console.log("2");
};

module.exports.createServer = function () {
   return new Server();
};
```

And to use it:

```
var server = require("./app/server").createServer();
```

If you want to be able to create instances of your server in "express fashion" you can use:

```
module.exports = function () {
   return new Server();
};
```

And to use that:

```
var server = require("./app/server")();
```